# Accessing the objects currently in Hazelcast Cache in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast

I want to access all the object present in Hazelcast cache through the cache manager and check them. How do I do it?

After autowiring the `cacheManager`, what needs to be done next?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation here: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10/manual/html-single/index.html#hazelcast-jcache

You can use standard `get` or `getAll` methods.

Alternatively, use `IMap` and you can run queries.